# It's better to use array or object to store structured data?

Tags: arrays, object

Let's say there's a photo contest with categories and prizes data. We can store the data as an array or object. I'm just wondering which is better.

array example:

```
var contest = {
    'name': 'Photo Contest',
    'categories': [
        {'name': 'landscape', 'type': 'single'},
        {'name': 'portrait', 'type': 'single'},
        {'name': 'food', 'type': 'single'},
    ],
    'prizes': [
        {'name': 'winner of the year', 'count': 1, 'cat': ''},
        {'name': '1st', 'count': 1, 'cat': 'landscape'},
        {'name': '2nd', 'count': 3, 'cat': 'landscape'},
        {'name': '3rd', 'count': 5, 'cat': 'landscape'},
        {'name': '1st', 'count': 1, 'cat': 'portrait'},
        {'name': '2nd', 'count': 3, 'cat': 'portrait'},
        {'name': '3rd', 'count': 5, 'cat': 'portrait'},
        {'name': '1st', 'count': 1, 'cat': 'food'},
        {'name': '2nd', 'count': 3, 'cat': 'food'},
        {'name': '3rd', 'count': 5, 'cat': 'food'}
    ]
}
```

object example:

```
var contest = {
    'name': 'Photo Contest',
    'categories': {
        'landscape': {'type': 'single'},
        'portrait': {'type': 'single'},
        'food': {'type': 'single'},
    },
    'prizes': {
        'winner of the year': {'count': 1, 'cat': ''},
        'landscape 1st': {'count': 1, 'cat': 'landscape'},
        'landscape 2nd': {'count': 3, 'cat': 'landscape'},
        'landscape 3rd': {'count': 5, 'cat': 'landscape'},
        'portrait 1st': {'count': 1, 'cat': 'portrait'},
        'portrait 2nd': {'count': 3, 'cat': 'portrait'},
        'portrait 3rd': {'count': 5, 'cat': 'portrait'},
        'food 1st': {'count': 1, 'cat': 'food'},
        'food 2nd': {'count': 3, 'cat': 'food'},
        'food 3rd': {'count': 5, 'cat': 'food'},
    }
}
```

I'm making a general contests management system. Admin user can create a new contest by input some information(with different categories and prizes). The front-end page will get these info and display.

There're maybe other usages with these data, like record the winners(after the contest closed) or for searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It depends on the way you use those code afterwards.*

- If you want to use those objects afterwards for access functions go with creating classes and objects.
- If this is for a small program just use an array.Don't bother with a classes or objects unless there's a need to. If you are writing a
  small module in a larger application, and no other things need to
  interface with your code, maybe an array is sufficient

Comment: thanks. I edited the post. Untill now, displaying is the main function. I perhaps will extend the functions later, like searching and data analysing and so on.

Comment: @BrickYang So as what i said, looks like to display only for the front page, better way is to go with array, but since you want to add this data for searching,analysing etc. better to go with objects.Unless you have to declare arrays again and again to get data,which causes data redundancy, which is not good practice.Hope this may help :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your intended use case is. If you want to *display* the results, it makes more sense to use an array. If you want to make a filter dialog which will let the user find only a particular subset of photos, use the object representation, since it better shows the underlying structure of the results.

Comment: thanks. I edited the post. Untill now, displaying is the main function. I perhaps will extend the functions later, like searching and data analysing and so on.